# Table size and Numbers of rows is not updated

Tags: google-bigquery

I've created an new table copying another existent (with an different name), but in Table info I don't see the table size and numbers of rows increase. If I run a query I see the new rows, but in preview mode the table seems static.

Comment: are you streaming data to the table?

Comment: yes, I use an insertAll in python code

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, when dealing with streaming data:

> Streamed data is available for real-time analysis within a few seconds
>   of the first streaming insertion into a table.
>
> Data can take up to 90 minutes to become available for copy and export
>   operations. Also, when streaming to a partitioned table, data in the
>   streaming buffer has a NULL value for the _PARTITIONTIME pseudo
>   column. To see whether data is available for copy and export, check
>   the tables.get response for a section named streamingBuffer. If that
>   section is absent, your data should be available for copy or export,
>   and should have a non-null value for the _PARTITIONTIME pseudo column.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery

Comment: Ok thanks, but I've created this post 6 days ago, and today I don't see anything yet :-(

Comment: It seems we'll need to debug this. Can you file a bug report at https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/entry?template=Bug%20Report ?